MassTransit JobConsumer concurrency not working
I'm trying to configure JobConsumer to run long running tasks. Regardless of the SetConcurrentJobLimit parameter, the tasks are run sequentially, only 1 at a time.
MassTransit setup
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<JobConsumer>(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Options<JobOptions<JobConsumer>>(options => options
            .SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
            .SetConcurrentJobLimit(20)
            );
    }).Endpoint(e => e.Name = "test-job-queue");

    x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    x.AddJobSagaStateMachines(
        options =>
        {
            options.FinalizeCompleted = false;
            options.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 100;
            options.SlotWaitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        }
    );
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(<connection parameters>);
        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

JobConsumer class:
public class JobConsumer : IJobConsumer<TestJob>
{
    public async Task Run(JobContext<TestJob> context)
    {
        await Task.Delay(60000);

    }
}

I tried to use PostgreSQL transport instead of RabbitMQ, but nothing changed.

There is a sample that works just fine. I'd suggest using it to figure out what's different about your solution.

I found It.
I needed to use the job class, not consumer class
cfg.Options<JobOptions<JobConsumer>>

working code
cfg.Options<JobOptions<TestJob>>

